# How can I blockquote a numbered list without resetting the number to 1?

Tags: support, markdown, list, blockquote

Let's say I want to put "50. Quoting point number 50." in a blockquote. By default it will reset the number to 1:

> 50. Quoting point number 50.

How can I preserve the initial number 50?

Comment: Too bad they haven't whitelisted the `start` attribute for ordered lists.

Answer (score 9):

If you don't want a list, you can escape the dot:

```
> 50\. Quoting point number 50.
```

Produces:

> 50. Quoting point number 50.

By the way, it works the same way without the quote block (`>`).

Comment: I didn't know this. +1  (Still, there is something that seems right about PRE tags for a quote.  I think I shall not delete my answer, unless you disagree.)

Answer (score 4):

This has been fixed. Now, the numbering follows from the first item in the list. If the first item in your list is 42, the numbering will follow from that. If the next item in your list is 1037, it will still show up as 43. So the *first* number in your numbered list is now respected; the others still aren’t.

1. This is a demonstration list.
2. This item is numbered 7, but shows up as 2.

And in blockquotes,

> 4. This is item 4.
> 5. And this item is numbered 8, but shows up as 5.

Comment: Link to post where fix is described: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239121/224428

Answer (score 2):

1. foo
2. bar

The thing you need is some separation.  This could be some text, or a comment.

This then does some funky things to the start of the *next* numbering block.

5. qux
6. baz

The above text is:

```
1. foo
2. bar

The thing you need is some separation.  This could be some text, or a comment.

This then does some funky things to the start of the *next* numbering block.

5. qux
2. baz
```

Note that this *is* the ordered list format and baz continues with picking up on the new numbering.