# Weirdness with numbers in my post

Tags: discussion, support, markdown

Here is a screen shot from one of my recent posts.
You can see inside the edit box after the or I've entered a "2." but in the preview display, and in the actual display on the page it turnend my 2 into a "1." Whats up with that? Is it thinking that I am starting two separate numbered lists or something since I put an or in the middle to break them up?

[image]

Comment: It's not really a bug, but [meta-tag:status-bydesign].  That's just the way two separate ordered lists work.  You might be interested in seeing [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113475/150562).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The others answers have explained what's happening -- but to get what you want, do this:

```
1. some stuff

  **or** (indented)

2. some other stuff
```

That gives:

1. some stuff

   **or** (indented)
2. some other stuff

The bolding should hopefully serve the same purpose as outdenting.

Answer (score 10):

This is a Markdown feature ("feature" -- personally I find it annoying). It's explained on the [editing help page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#simple-lists):

> A numbered `<ol>` list:
>
> `1. Numbered lists are easy`
> `2. Markdown keeps track of the numbers for you`
> `7. So this will be item 3.`

Answer (score 6):

Yes, that's what happened. It seems that numbered lists are detected with a regular expression that takes any number as valid in that context, but then the numbers are replaced automatically. Observe that the reverse will also happen: when I write

```
// Put this inside a code block so that auto-formatting does not kick in
1. Item 1
1. Item 2
```

It comes out as:

1. Item 1
2. Item 2