# How do I stop posting code from autoformatting my numbers into lists?

Tags: support, markdown, markdown-rendering

I'm [attempting to post a dictionary definition in an answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/10814/289). It is definition #4 on the site I'm linking to, and that information can be important to preserve when there are many definitions for a given word. I'm attempting to paste the definition into a formatting block like this:

> 4. Definition goes here.

Hey, wait a minute; that's a 1, not a 4! Yep, that's exactly my problem. Take a look at the code for that line above:

`> 4. Definition goes here.`

I typed a 4, but the auto formatter thingy assumes I'm writing a numbered list, and of course a numbered list must begin at 1! So it displays as a 1, even though I tell it 4.

What super secret magic can I use to fix this problem?

Comment: One of the most annoying features of markdown. The lack of means to override the starting number is decidedly a misfeature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I do is escape the period:

```
> 4\. Definition goes here.
```

> 4. Definition goes here.

This basically prevents it from rendering as a list, resulting in the literal text "4. Definition goes here."

Comment: Cool. I always wrapped my numbers in `<span></span>` tags, but this is neater.

Comment: No. This is stupid. It should start at 4, not 1. I shouldn't have to escape anything.

Comment: @ColeJohnson Agreed; perhaps that should be a feature request? I'm glad enough to just have the number appearing with BoltClock's trick, but it would be nice to be able to begin an actual list at whatever number I choose.

Comment: @WendiKidd add the tag then.

Comment: No need, it's already been asked many times over: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137077/cant-start-a-numbered-list-on-a-number-other-than-1