# Why are the numbers in my question offset by 1?

Tags: discussion

I've answered a question (perhaps not particularly well) here:

[What's the most effective methods to reverse engineer and understand complex software?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48499515/whats-the-most-effective-methods-to-reverse-engineer-and-understand-complex-sof/48499557#48499557)

I had introduced a step 0, but when the markdown was actually displayed, it renumbered my sequence from 1, which messes up any references to the points in later commentary.

I've worked around this for now, starting, more normally, the list from 1. But is this intentional behaviour?

---

A simple reproduction here. Note that if you edit this question, you'll see the numbering starts at 0.

1. Zero
2. One

Comment: Eh this isn't really a duplicate of the other. The other was closed as a duplicate of a different question because *at the time* changing the numbering wasn't possible at all, and thus a request for starting at 0 was no  different than a request for being able to start somewhere other than 1. But now we can start at places other than 1, and 0 still doesn't work as an option.

Comment: @animuson You have a source for that? I couldn't find such information.

Comment: It looks like you can start numbering by any positive integer: neither `-1` nor `0` work. Note also that [2,147,483,647](https://stackoverflow.com/a/94608/1983854) is the biggest allowed number; afther that, it goes into `1` again.

Comment: @PatrickHofman For starting at numbers other than 1? Follow the duplicate link on the question you linked. :)

Comment: [Which is here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239121/245360)