# Where are all the bullets and numbers for my lists?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, list

They took not only the letters but the bullets for all the lists. Now my list of reasons we need to have bullets is lacking:

1. Nobody is really anti-bulleted lists
2. We need them

   - Not only that, other people need them

([Screenshot for posterity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyXic.png))

Markdown:

```
1. Nobody is really anti-bulleted lists
2. We need them
   - Not only that, other people need them
```

It's happening on both my computer and my phone.

Something must be done!

Comment: Certainly a bug, looking at the CommonMark spec [5.2. List Items](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/#list-items) namely [example 254](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/#example-254) your numbered list should work. Looking at [this older post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137077) the number on the list item is also gone...

Comment: wow `ol,ul{list-style:none}` in [stacks.css](https://meta.stackexchange.com/Content/Shared/stacks.css?v=9845c18381cd) 

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a CSS reset issue that is deploying now. For historical reasons, we allow for Stacks to be configurable with 2 different CSS resets. Our testing environment had one. Production had the other. How fun!

We're exploring not having *any* CSS reset in the future, but this is now fixed.

Comment: Oh! My post is fixed bow :-)